# macOS terminal sudo not working

Tags: terminal, sudo

My sudo command is not working. After I type sudo and hit enter (or type sudo with some command and hit enter), the cursor moves to the next line which remains blank. It does not ask my password or anything, just a blank line. I can type in this, and hit enter, but then it just goes to a new blank line.
How can I fix this? I dont understand because sudo always worked for me, i.e., it asked me my password. See screenshot below.

[image]

UPDATE: It does work eventually, it just takes like 5 minutes. Why?

Comment: What does `type sudo` print? Also, try `/usr/bin/sudo ls` and see what it prints.

Comment: Same problem after update to 10.12.4.

Comment: Seems to I fixed by install [this sudo](https://www.sudo.ws/sudo/dist/packages/macOS/10.12/sudo-1.8.19p2.pkg)

Comment: what happen when you try to logout? example here: [logout](http://www.clihelp.org/MO00143/log-out-user)

Comment: What is the purpose of `sudo cd` at all? I agree that it should return immediately but the command itself doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Please post the fix as an answer instead of amending the question.

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271193/why-is-sudo-taking-way-too-long?rq=1

Comment: I'm not sure at all, but could the be related to disk permissions?