# How to fix "sudo" waiting a minute on macOS?

Tags: terminal, command-line, sudo

On my MacBook Air (macOS 12.5) I need to use the `sudo` command quite often. And I noticed that when I use `sudo` on the command line it sometimes takes a very long time before the prompt to enter the password shows up.

I just tried with:

```
sudo ls
```

and here it was about immediately. But just before I renamed a folder:

```
sudo mv python3.8/ bak_python3.8
```

and it took a minute(!) before the password prompt showed up.

Why is that? And how can I fix this problem?

There is a similar question [HERE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271193/why-is-sudo-taking-way-too-long) but the answer does not work for me. In step 3 I get an error `cp: /private/etc/sudoers~orig: No such file or director`.

Comment: I assume your MBA is not so busy that commands take a long time to execute. Did you make any changes to /etc/sudoers?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: What is the output of `type sudo`? When `sudo` hangs, what is the output of `top -o CPU -stats pid,command,cpu,time,mem,ppid,state,user -l 2 -n 10 | sed '1,22d'` (this command lists the 10 most CPU-intensive processes)?

Comment: First command gives `sudo is hashed (/usr/bin/sudo)`, second command I have to wait when this happens again

Comment: Not that this fixes `sudo`, but what is so broken that you have to use `sudo` "quite often"?  Is that a symptom of some other breakage?

Comment: @MarcWilson I use `sudo` daily, without anything being broken.

Comment: @MarcWilson I have to use `sudo` to play music continuously (instead of broken every then which is very annoying), to unmount disks, and folders etc

Comment: If you need sudo often, maybe just run `sudo -s` once and keep the shell open.